# XML forms - show input based on condition type

Tags: json, xml, forms

Having an .xml file that creates forms based on actions CRUD on my application, i need to display input boxes based on conditions, the goal is to show an input based on which radio button is selected, and i can't figure how to do it.

Heres my code that works, i have two inputs: 'entrydate' and 'endsubmissiondate':

```
 <action name="search" jsonMetainfo="{
          'tabs':[
              {'order':1, 'key':'filter', 'active':true},
          ],'form':[
              {'order':1, 'tab': 1, 'key':'code', 'required': false,'allowSort':true, 'type':'text', 'exportable':true},
              {'order':2, 'tab': 1, 'key':'title', 'required': false, 'type': 'text'},
              {'order':4,'tab': 1, 'key':'entryDate', 'required': false, 'type': 'date'},
              {'order':5,'tab': 1, 'key':'endSubmissionDate', 'type': 'date'},
              ...   
          ]}"/>
```

but now i want that endsubmissiondate only shows if i select a radio button with key='y', heres what i've tryed:

```
<action name="search" jsonMetainfo="{
          'tabs':[
              {'order':1, 'key':'filter', 'active':true},
          ],'form':[
              {'order':1,'tab': 1, 'key':'code', 'required': false,'allowSort':true, 'type':'text', 'exportable':true},
              {'order':2,'tab': 1, 'key':'title', 'required': false, 'type': 'text'},
              {'order':5,'tab': 1, 'key':'endentryDate', 'type': 'radioButton', 'options':[{'key':'n', 'value':'NoEnd'},{'key':'y', 'value':'End'}]},
              {'order':6,'tab': 1, 'key':'endSubmissionDate', 'type': 'date', 'condition':{'field': 'endentryDate','operator':'=', 'condition':'y'}},
              ...   
          ]}"/>
```

So, *endentryDate* is a radio button with options (n,y)
*endSubmissionDate* is a date that has a condition to appear bases on field *endentryDate*, with operator '=' and condition 'y'.

With that code i have the entrydate and endsubmissiondate displayed, and if i select any of the options i got no change of the form whatsoever. 
How can i archieve what i want?